# Modify characters of mt2pro[lite] using Times

Tags: fonts, symbols, mtpro, times

I wish to know if is possible to modify the following MWE adding only a few characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}% 
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\def\xyz{(x,y,z)}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \varphi \xyz}{\partial x}\hat{\textbf x}+\frac{\partial \varphi  \xyz}{\partial y}\hat{\textbf y}+\frac{\partial \varphi \xyz}{\partial z}\hat{\textbf z}.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\frac{\vardelta \varphi \xyz}{\vardelta x}\hat{\textbf x}+\frac{\vardelta \varphi  \xyz}{\vardelta y}\hat{\textbf y}+\frac{\vardelta \varphi \xyz}{\vardelta z}\hat{\textbf z}.\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} v\,dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In particular, I don’t like the symbol `\partial` (eq. 1) or `\vardelta` (eq. 2), but with the Times font there is exactly the partial symbol that I like (∂) (Unicode cod. 2202) (see formula (eq.1) and (eq.2)).

[image]

Is it possible to change the symbol `\partial` or `\vardelta` with the symbol ∂ (i.e. with `\DeclaremathOperator` or `\DeclareMathSymbol`) that is very nice?

After, is there the possibility, too, for the same reason, to have a different **vertical integral sign** for all the types of integrals always with `mt2pro[lite]` and `Times` (eq. 3) and to add the tensor symbol (a special character bold)? You can see the second image.

[image]

I hope to have your help. Best regards.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the upright integrals and the partial symbol of NewTX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book} 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\DeclareFontEncoding{LMX}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsTX}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsTX}{bold}{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsTXA}{U}{ntxexa}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsTXA}{bold}{U}{ntxexa}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{ntxexa}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}                {\mathop}{largesymbolsTX}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}               {\mathop}{largesymbolsTX}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}              {\mathop}{largesymbolsTX}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}               {\mathop}{largesymbolsTX}{"B7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}              {\mathop}{largesymbolsTX}{"B8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintop}             {\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varointclockwiseop}   {\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointctrclockwiseop}   {\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumintop}             {\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiiintop}             {\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fintop}               {\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqintop}              {\mathop}{largesymbolsTXA}{"25}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{nxlmi}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
  <8.6->    nxlmi0
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{b}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlbmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlbmi07
  <8.6->    nxlbmi0
}{}

\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}


\newcommand\xyz{(x,y,z)}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \varphi \xyz}{\partial x}\hat{\textbf{x}}+
\frac{\partial \varphi  \xyz}{\partial y}\hat{\textbf{y}}+
\frac{\partial \varphi \xyz}{\partial z}\hat{\textbf{z}}.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} v\,dt
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for your answer. Very good too. But for the bold letter `F`?

Comment: @Sebastiano `\mathsf{F}`

Comment: Okay you're the number one :) I write it with all your heart, without you I would never have done it. I'm doing a job for a teacher you know about Physics General 2 in Catania.

Comment: Sir egreg best wishes for 1 million points....hats off to you

Answer (score 2):

You can get the \partial like this (I assume you want the normal from cm-fonts). I don't know which integral you want. But if you add an example that shows it, it should be easy to add it too.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{cmletters}{"40}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}%
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\def\xyz{(x,y,z)}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \varphi \xyz}{\partial x}\hat{\textbf x}+\frac{\partial \varphi  \xyz}{\partial y}\hat{\textbf y}+\frac{\partial \varphi \xyz}{\partial z}\hat{\textbf z}.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\frac{\vardelta \varphi \xyz}{\vardelta x}\hat{\textbf x}+\frac{\vardelta \varphi  \xyz}{\vardelta y}\hat{\textbf y}+\frac{\vardelta \varphi \xyz}{\vardelta z}\hat{\textbf z}.\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} v\,dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]