# How Import partial symbol

Tags: math-fonts

[image: I want to write the partial symbol like the picture]

I need import a partial symbol like this

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Why to you need to import it, given that, in math mode, `\partial` provides it directly.  If you still need to import it, from where do you need to import it?

Comment: I need import it for the mtpro2 package

Answer (score 3):

The partial symbol is similar as your picture (I think). I have used `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` as you have indicated in your request.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[\frac{\partial w}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\]
\end{document}
```

For another symbol of partial you can see this my question [Modify characters of mt2pro[lite] using Times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366290/modify-characters-of-mt2prolite-using-times)

**ADDENDUM after the comments of the user:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{nxlmi}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
  <8.6->    nxlmi0
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{b}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlbmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlbmi07
  <8.6->    nxlbmi0
}{}

\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}

\begin{document}
\[\frac{\partial w}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how import it from the package?

Comment: There's nothing to import. It is by default. If the question had been: you can change the partial derivative symbol to another font style as you like? The answer is yes. You must call the symbol with a macro as in the link that I reported at the bottom of the page. Obviously you have to install the package `mt2pro` from https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite.

Comment: Yes I need to change only the partial symbol bucause I use the package mathptmx and I don't like the symbol of the partial of this package

Comment: @erika21148 Now is it perfect? :-)