# On the math Belleek font: how to use it?

Tags: fonts, packages

I am writing a little expository note on the Poisson equation. During the redaction of the note, due to the simplicity of the content, I decided to experiment with mathematical fonts: I experimented many of the ones listed in the nice Stephen G. Hartke's "*[A Survey of Free Math Fonts for TEX and LATEX](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf)*". When I tried to use the `Belleek` font package, (p. 15 of the paper quoted above), I checked if it was installed in my TEXLive installation (MACTEX) and I loaded it by issuing the command `\usepackage{mathtime}` (as stated in the paper), but it failed (`ERROR: LaTeX Error: File 'mathtime.sty' not found`). So my question: how could I use that math font?

**Few infos**

- My machine is an iMac macOS 10.14.5
  -The TEXLIVE utility I've installed is Version 1.35.

Here follows an example code:

```
%********************************************************************
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%********************************************************************
%            Packages
%********************************************************************
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtime}
\newcommand{\dm}{\mathrm{d}}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theo}{Teorema}
%********************************************************************
%            Content
%********************************************************************
\author{Daniele Tampieri}
\title{La condizione necessaria e sufficiente per la soluzione del problema di Neumann per l'equazione di Poisson.}
\begin{document}
Testo di prova
\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}= f(x,y,z)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: mathtime is not in texlive (probably as it is meant to support non-free fonts). In miktex your example works without problems. For texlive you will have to install the support files manually, e.g. mathtime is here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/mathtime.

Answer (score 2):

You could to try the lite version of MathTime Pro­fes­sional 2 using the package `mtpro2` (basic version) `lite`, `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`.

If you want necessary to use Bellek font (see this link https://ctan.org/pkg/belleek - I don't think it's part of the classic LaTeX distribution) download and install it. Into my previous old answer [Latest MiKTeX: suggestions on how to install new fonts using the MiKTeX Console](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419957/latest-miktex-suggestions-on-how-to-install-new-fonts-using-the-miktex-console), you could see for example, the correct mechanism of how to install new fonts. I unfortunately use Windows with MikTeX and I think that on Mac there is a similar mechanism.

I think that could be very useful this link to an old answer that I just edited ([Font installation in TeXShop on a Mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49736/font-installation-in-texshop-on-a-mac)) http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/.

[image]

```
%********************************************************************
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%********************************************************************

%********************************************************************
%            Packages
%********************************************************************
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\newcommand{\dm}{\mathrm{d}}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theo}{Teorema}
%********************************************************************
%            Content
%********************************************************************
\author{Daniele Tampieri}
\title{La condizione necessaria e sufficiente per la soluzione del problema di Neumann per l'equazione di Poisson.}
\begin{document}
Testo di prova
\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}= f(x,y,z)
\]
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:** If you prefer to use a more rounded symbol for the partial derivate I can suggest you both this code and it refers to my previous answer: [How Import partial symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473353/how-import-partial-symbol)

[image]

```
%********************************************************************
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%********************************************************************

%********************************************************************
%            Packages
%********************************************************************
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{nxlmi}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
  <8.6->    nxlmi0
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{b}{it}{
  <-6.3>    nxlbmi05
  <6.3-8.6> nxlbmi07
  <8.6->    nxlbmi0
}{}

\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}

\newcommand{\dm}{\mathrm{d}}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theo}{Teorema}
%********************************************************************
%            Content
%********************************************************************
\author{Daniele Tampieri}
\title{La condizione necessaria e sufficiente per la soluzione del problema di Neumann per l'equazione di Poisson.}
\begin{document}
Testo di prova
\[
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}= f(x,y,z)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: To the user who voted against my reply just edited: I would like to have a comment. Thank you.

Comment: Sebastiano, thank you for your help. I upvoted immediately your answer: I will try your suggestions and experiment the installation of the `mathtimes` non free font (it seems that Belleek, despite being a free substitute, needs that font "infrastructure" to work. Then, if I'll succeed, I'll come back and accept your answer.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri I don't care about the votes, but help you and others. In these two and a half years I have understood thanks to all the many aspects and strategies that I did not know about LaTeX, but I am against those who vote negatively just for the sake of damaging as has happened so many times to me. If you don't want to install anything but use the full TeXLive distribution with all the available packages you could use this combination: `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}`. If you have any problems, contact us and I,like so many others, will be here to help you.My greetings from Sicily.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano. My greetings from Romagna.