# A strange partial symbol into newtx package

Tags: fonts, symbols, compilation-error, mtpro, newtx

Considering that in these weeks the `newtx` package is changing versions continuously from my old question [Modify characters of mt2pro[lite] using Times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366290/modify-characters-of-mt2prolite-using-times), using this MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Nuovo \partial
    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{nxlmi}{}
    \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
      <-6.3>    nxlmi05
      <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
      <8.6->    nxlmi0
    }{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{nxlmi}{b}{it}{
      <-6.3>    nxlbmi05
      <6.3-8.6> nxlbmi07
      <8.6->    nxlbmi0
    }{}
\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}

\begin{document}
\[\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial \overline{E}}{\partial t}\]
\end{document}
```

I obtained these `\partial` symbol (number 64 of `newtx` package).

[image]

But compiling with TeXWorks (with last update of MikTeX) I have obtained another symbol, as from image,

[image]

The font is pretty but it is small compared to the size of the lowercase and uppercase of each characther. Now also if I remove the command `\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{nxlmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}` I will have the `\partial` symbol of `mtpro2` *lite*.

I have not obtain the `\partial` symbol that exist into the guide of `newtx`. Why and what is the strategy to get the partial symbol of the first image?

### ADDENDUM 2019/11/1:

As suggested by the very good author of `newtx` Michael Sharpe that I thank so much, the font `nxlmi` and its variants contain symbols from Libertine, and are called 
when I supply the `libertine` option to `newtxmath`. It is `ntxmi` and variants that contain the symbols appropriate to `newtxtext`. Therefore I have changed my original code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmi}{}
    \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}{
      <-6.3>    nxlmi05
      <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
      <8.6->    nxlmi0
    }{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmi}{b}{it}{
      <-6.3>    ntxbmi05
      <6.3-8.6> ntxbmi07
      <8.6->    ntxbmi0
    }{}
\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\partial t
\]
\end{document}
```

But with the new code I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\partial ->{\text 
                  {\usefont {U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}\symbol {64}}\mspace {1mu}}
l.23 \partial
              t
?
```

If I remove the new definition of `\partial` -- `\renewcommand{\partial}{{\text{\usefont{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}}` -- I get default `\partial` symbol of the package `mtpro2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmi}{}
    \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}{
      <-6.3>    nxlmi05
      <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
      <8.6->    nxlmi0
    }{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmi}{b}{it}{
      <-6.3>    ntxbmi05
      <6.3-8.6> ntxbmi07
      <8.6->    ntxbmi0
    }{}


\begin{document}
\[
\partial t
\]
\end{document}
```

How can I solve the problem? I am waiting patiently for an possible answer.

Comment: Apparently, the character has changed in the last version of `newtxmath`. Just remove the redefinition of `\partial`.

Comment: The error message shows up because of the unrecognized `\text` command. Load the `amsmath` package to get rid of the error message.

Comment: @Mico Addendum: On my `structure.tex` for my book I have loaded `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` but I have always the new symbol :-(. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano - The `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package automatically. :-)

Comment: @Mico Yes, I know :-)...I have tried your suggestion but I have always the new symbol. :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano - Please see the answer I just posted. To me, there's a significant visual distinction between the two `\partial` styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

There have several updates to the `newtxmath` package in recent days. In what follows below, I use the version that's current as of today, i.e., 1 November 2019.

First off, here's what I get when I load the `mtpro2` package and run `$\partial\ \scriptstyle\partial\ \scriptscriptstyle\partial$` in the body of the document:

[image]

Next, here's what I get when I load the `newtxmath` package. The upper row is without the `\renewcommand` instruction, while the lower row is with the redefinition of `\partial`. To me, there's not a huge, but still an easy-to-spot visual difference.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
    \DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmi}{}
    \DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}{
          <-6.3>    nxlmi05
          <6.3-8.6> nxlmi07
          <8.6->    nxlmi0
        }{}
    \DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmi}{b}{it}{
          <-6.3>    ntxbmi05
          <6.3-8.6> ntxbmi07
          <8.6->    ntxbmi0
        }{}

\begin{document}
$\partial\ \scriptstyle\partial\ \scriptscriptstyle\partial$

\renewcommand{\partial}{\text{\usefont{U}{ntxmi}{m}{it}\symbol{64}}\mspace{1mu}}

$\partial\ \scriptstyle\partial\ \scriptscriptstyle\partial$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Most kind Mico but isn't there another family of fonts as `ntxmi` into `DeclareFontFamily....` that provides a better new `\partial` than `newtx`?

Comment: @Sebastiano - I'm afraid I've kind of lost track of your objectives. Which math font package(s) do you employ, and which style of `\partial` are you trying to achieve? If you're using `newtxmath` and if you want a more "upright" partial symbol, give `\uppartial` a try.

Comment: As you well know I use `newtxtext` with `mtpro2` (no `newtxmath`) and do not change these packages :-). Don't worry you've done the maximum of the maximum. Thank you always for everything from the heart.